# jQuery scripts not working on my Drupal theme

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

This script from JSFiddle that works: https://jsfiddle.net/ryXFt/704/

Does not work in my Drupal theme (yes, it does load, I can see it via Firebug). All I do is just wrap up the code to match Drupal rules.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.yourBehaviorName = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        $("#block-menu-menu-mobile ul li .nolink").click(function() {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".region-front-calander").offset().top},
                'slow');
        });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

When clicked, console gives `TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is null` for line that contains `scrollTop: $(".region-front-calander").offset().top},`

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <div id="main">
                <div id="content" class="column" role="main">
                    <div class="region region-highlighted">
                        <div id="block-menu-menu-mobile" class="block block-menu first odd" role="navigation">
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li class="first leaf">
                                    <span class="nolink" title="">Calendar</span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="region region-front-calendar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the html of the dom objects your trying to work with?

Comment: Hi, I added the HTML code.

Comment: Does `"#block-menu-menu-mobile ul li .nolink"` exist? Is it clickable? What appears in JS console when you click it? Is your function called at all? With error? No error but nothing visible happens?.. Scrolling attempt might get unnoticed if the problem is with your CSS, for example.

Comment: When clicked console gives 'TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is null'. It does exist., I just posted the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your classes aren't matching up. I'm guessing that the ideal action you want is when you click on the calendar link, it brings the region-front-calendar up.

The issue looks like your js isn't doing anything to that region, rather it's attempting to pull up a class called "second" which dosn't exist in the html snippet you posted.

If you switch that to the region-front-calander, that might be the answer your looking for.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.yourBehaviorName = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        $("#block-menu-menu-mobile ul li .nolink").click(function() {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".region-front-calander").offset().top},
                'slow');
        });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You're right, I forgot to replace the class from .second to .region-front-calander, but after replacing it's still not working. Console gives TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is null

Comment: Nevermind, the issue was the typo. Not calander, but calendar.